How to use Python as backend with VScode extenstion?
I have a Python program that takes a file and output it as AST tree in a JSON format.
I want to take that JSON output and render it as a tab in VScode.
My main issue is how to run both as one extension and can communicate together?
Should I spawn a subprocess from VScode extension that runs the Python program as API with POST functions,
or should I use Language Server Protocol (LSP) with Python?
What I tried:
Using LSP: found some templates from Python tools (formatting/linting) but I don't know how to send the result to the typescript code and render it.
I think I'm using LSP for not it's intended use.
Regarding the subprocess, it's hard to track and debug. I prefer if there is an another solution.
There might be other than LSP or subprocess but I haven't found it yet.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
